# Angular 5 Material centering a span into a mat-header-cell

Tags: html, css, angular, angular5

On my angular5 application I am using material table to display some data.

Into a `mat-header-cell` I am having a `span` and a `img` together and trying to align them properly.

Here how it looks right now :

[image]

Here the piece html code :

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="batchState">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="border: 1px solid white;"> 
    <span style="border: 1px solid white;">Batch state </span>
    <img style="border: 1px solid white;" src='../../assets/filter_list.png' (click)="filterByState()" 
        matTooltip="Filter by state" />
</mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let inst">
        {{inst.batchState}} 
</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

I want my `span` to be displayed at the center-left of the cell, tried `text-align:center; left:0px;` and  `padding-top: 25%; padding-bottom: 25%` (inside my span element) but those css did not work, any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found adding css to the `mat-header-cell` -> `display: flex; align-items: center;`

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="batchState">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="border: 1px solid white;display: flex; align-items: center;"> 
    <span style="border: 1px solid white;">Batch state </span>
    <img style="border: 1px solid white;" src='../../assets/filter_list.png' (click)="filterByState()" 
        matTooltip="Filter by state" />
</mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let inst">
        {{inst.batchState}} 
</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

[image]